# SPOJ Water solution, bfs implementation JAVA bug

Tags: java, algorithm, graph-algorithm

[Link to the problem](http://www.spoj.com/problems/WATER/)

I'm a newby in such hard algorithms, but after ~30 hours i got the code below.

With small maps it works like this:

```
1
5 5
1 3 5 6 3
3 2 1 1 3
4 2 5 1 5
6 3 4 9 3
5 7 2 1 1

Output: 8
```

But with huge maps - 50x50 1000-height I find a strange bug:

I have different results by changing ***DIRECTION*** static places inside.

Any ideas how to solve this bug?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.*;

public class Island_flood {
    final static int[][] DIRECTIONS = {{0, 1}, {0, -1}, {1, 0}, {-1, 0}};

    public static class Island {
        int islandHeight, islandWidth;
        boolean[][] visited;
        Block[][] islandMap;

        public Island(BufferedReader reader) throws IOException {
            String[] islandSizes = reader.readLine().split(" ");

            this.islandHeight = Integer.parseInt(islandSizes[0]);
            this.islandWidth = Integer.parseInt(islandSizes[1]);
            this.visited = new boolean[islandHeight][islandWidth];
            this.islandMap = new Block[islandHeight][islandWidth];

            for (int i = 0; i < this.islandHeight; i++) {
                String[] blocksRow = reader.readLine().split(" ");
                for (int j = 0; j< this.islandWidth; j++) {
                    this.islandMap[i][j] = new Block(Integer.parseInt(blocksRow[j]));
                    this.islandMap[i][j].isBorder = i == 0 || j == 0 || i == islandHeight - 1 || j == islandWidth - 1;
                }
            }
        }

        public int getTotalWaterLevel() {
            int result = 0;

            for (int i = 1; i < islandHeight - 1; i++) {
                for (int j = 1; j < islandWidth - 1; j++) {
                    bfs(new int[]{i, j});
                    int floodedValue = getFloodedValue(islandMap[i][j]);
                    int waterLevel = floodedValue - islandMap[i][j].value;
                    islandMap[i][j].value = floodedValue;
                    result += waterLevel;

                    visited = new boolean[islandHeight][islandWidth];

                    for (Block[] blockRow : islandMap) {
                        for (Block block : blockRow) {
                            block.children = new ArrayList<>();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return result;
        }

        public void bfs(int[] s) {
            Queue<int[]> queue = new LinkedList<>();
            queue.offer(s);

            visited[s[0]][s[1]] = true;

            while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
                int[] p = queue.poll();
                Block b = islandMap[p[0]][p[1]];

                if (!b.isBorder) {
                    for (int[] DIRECTION : DIRECTIONS) {
                        int xPos = p[0] + DIRECTION[0];
                        int yPos = p[1] + DIRECTION[1];

                        if (!visited[xPos][yPos]) {
                            visited[xPos][yPos] = !visited[xPos][yPos];
                            b.children.add(islandMap[xPos][yPos]);
                            queue.offer(new int[]{xPos, yPos});
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public static int getFloodedValue(Block block) {
            int result = 0;

            if (block.isBorder) {
                result = block.value;
            } else {
                ArrayList<Integer> childrenValues = new ArrayList<>();

                if (block.children.size() > 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < block.children.size(); i++) {
                            childrenValues.add(getFloodedValue(block.children.get(i)));
                    }

                    int minChildrenValue = Collections.min(childrenValues);

                    result = minChildrenValue > block.value ? minChildrenValue : block.value;
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int islandCount = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
        ArrayList<Island> islands = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < islandCount; i++) {
            Island island = new Island(reader);
            islands.add(island);
        }

        for (Island island : islands) System.out.println(island.getTotalWaterLevel());

        reader.close();
    }

    public static class Block {
        public boolean isBorder;
        public int value;
        public ArrayList<Block> children = new ArrayList<>();

        public Block(int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to figure out what is going on?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Few suggestions to help you getting started and eventually help us answer your question. 1. When you are referring to a question that is not from SO, it is better to also add a short description of it - in case the link will not work in the future. 2. Explain your solution, why do you think using BFS will solve this, etc. 3. If you have a bug - show us the exact results / outputs and why do you think it's a bug.

Comment: Yes, I might add, for clarity, the graph is constructed in a different order when changing DIRECTIONS elements place, respectively calculations are different and wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, some later ill change some info here.

Comment: You need to post an example where the problem happens. Try to find a small one, if possible.

Comment: @RemizovAlexander you must edit your question if you want us to be able to help out. Currently, it is impossible to track down your bug just with seeing this bunch of code.